# Is it possible to run a single Swift file main() within Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm currently working on a project with many files and I'm sometimes looking to run just a block of code without building and running the whole target.

Is there any way to do this, like it is with Android Studio by simply creating a :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Some random code
}
```

I only found some tips to do that with gcc that only apply for ObjC code.
Also, using an online sandbox does not work either since I need to reference different types inside my project.

Comment: Look into xCode playgrounds.

Comment: XCTests Would aslo work

Comment: I tried your solutions but I find it is way too much work when you just want to quickly run a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a *main.swift* file to your project containing this code:

```
import UIKit
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        .bindMemory(
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
    nil,
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Now locate your app delegate swift file and delete the term `@UIApplicationMain`.

Now build and run, to prove to yourself that the app still works...

Now you can comment out the `UIApplicationMain` call and add top-level code as desired. But be warned, this may not work as expected, because you are now trying to operate outside the application framework.

Comment: By removing the term @UIApplicationMain and then creating the main.swift file with your snippet I get the following error:
_expressions are not allowed at the top level_

Comment: @Slowbro Obviously I don't know what _you_ did. But I assure you that this does work; you can download a working example project from my book, here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk1ch06p297main/bk1ch06p297main